# Why is the output 1?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
       int x = 5, y = 10, z = 10;    

       x = y == z;          // This computational expression causes the value of x to be 1. I fail to understand why
       printf("%d\n", x); //Why is the value of x 1 here.

}
```

I fail to understand the statement `x = y ==z;`

According to me - x = 10 since y == z. z=10 and is stated to be equivalent to y. The value of y is then assigned to x - `x = y`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying different statements on my compiler to see what happens for operators '=' and '=='. I have edited and made my code more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign the result of the comparison »Is `y` equal to `z`« to `x`, which is `1`, i.e. true.

Note the different operators:

```
x = ... // assignment
y == z  // comparison with either 0 (false) or 1 (true) result
```

Let's break the program down a little bit further:

1. You initialize `x` to 5 and `y` and `z` to 10.
2. You perform a *comparison* (see above) of `y` and `z` without caring for the result. So that's a line that can safely be ignored. But it results in `1` since `y` is equal to `z`.
3. You print the current values of all three variables.
4. You perform the same comparison, this time assigning the result to `x`. `x` now has the value »Is `y` equal to `z`«, which is `1` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate answer to my unnecessarily complex code. I was just trying what different statements did for assignment as well as comparison operator. I just misunderstood the == operator first.

Answer (score 3):

Because of operators precedence

```
x = y == z;
```

is the same as

```
x = (y == z);
```

Now as `y == z` evaluates to  `1`, so `x`  value is `1` after the statement.

Answer (score 2):

y == z returns 1 if they are the same and 0 if they are not and the result of this is set to x

Answer (score 2):

`==` is a comparison operator, so will return 1 (true) if both of the operands are equal and 0 (false) if they are not.

The statement `x = y == z` is equivalent to `x = (y == z)`, because `==` has a higher precedence than `=`. Because y is equal to z, this will assign `1` to x.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Operator Precedence Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence). `==` (Comparison Operator) has a higher precedence over `=` (Assignment Operator). So, the y == z gets executed first and then yields result of 1 as y and z are having the same values which results in x being assigned a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator and `==` is the comparison operator. you compare `y` and `z`, they are equal, so the comparison returns true which is 1. this value is assigned to `x`.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the '==' part. Now i get it. Since, it is the comparison operator, it would return the value 1, for being true and then assign it to x. Thank you duedl0r.

Answer (score 1):

the `==` operator acts first.
Hence it becomes x= (value of y==z);
now since y and z are the same, the value of y==z is 1 that gets assigned to x.

Answer (score 0):

`==` has a greater precedence than `=`.

1. The expression `y == z` is evaluated to `1`.
2. The instruction `x = y == z` puts `1` in `x`.
3. The instruction `printf("%d\n", x);` prints the value of `x` (`1`).

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of `==` operator is higher than `=` operator.

y==z evaluates to 1; since both are equal.

Thisn value gets assigned to x.